# Need a more efficient way of doing an id comparison

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So I've been trying to different ids with switch statements. I just want to know if there is another efficient way as the number of id's could increase and i wouldn't want a lot of case statements.

Here is my current code.

```
            foreach (var rl in invalidItemsLogModel)
            switch(rl.ErrorCategoryType)
            {
                case 1:
                    rl.ErrorDescription = Resources.Misc.InvalidItemGridText.ErrorMandatoryField;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rl.ErrorDescription = Resources.Misc.InvalidItemGridText.AKACountryCodeApplied;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rl.ErrorDescription = Resources.Misc.InvalidItemGridText.ErrorFutureIssueDate;
                    break;

                default: break;
            }
```

Is there another way i could possibly loop through id's without having to create a new case statement for each id?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this code? If you have to differ between the categorytype on every element, you of course need the categoyr for every element by looping them. You may use some LINQ of course, however that only hides the complexity away. Behind the scenes the exact same things will happen.

Comment: You could use a design pattern eg. Chain of responsibility: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary...

```
var errorMessages = new Dictionary<int, String>(){
    {1, Resources.Misc.InvalidItemGridText.ErrorMandatoryField},
    ... etc
}

rl.ErrorDescription = errorMessages[ErrorCategoryType];
```

Comment: Thank you! I have applied the dictionary and it's looking much better now.

Answer (score 2):

use an array for your error text

```
string[] errors = new { null, ErrorMandatoryField, 
 AKACountryCodeApplied,ErrorFutureIssueDate};

foreach (var rl in invalidItemsLogModel)
    if (rl.ErrorCategoryType < errors.Length)
        rl.ErrorDescription = error[rl.ErrorCategoryType];
```

If your error-codes are non-continuous, then a switch is already optimal. It will decide itself if using a table or a Dictionary for the lookup. The performance gain is minimal in this case, I think there isn't any at all, cause switch does exactly the same, as my code-snippet does.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try implementing this way and see how it works too.